# ADB logcat batch never ends

Tags: batch-file, adb, android-logcat

I am trying to create a batch file that will do some ADB commands that I use on a daily basis. I am stuck with adb logcat because the logcat never ends. Is there a way to end it after so many seconds? Currently I have

```
:logcat
adb logcat
pause>nul|set /p "=Press any key to return to the menu"<nul&echo(
cls
goto start
```

Thinking that pause would allow me to manually end it when I was done getting what I needed from the log.

Is there a way to end the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

`timeout DURATION adb logcat`

to stop the logcat after DURATION (default is in seconds).

Another way of using adb is:

```
adb logcat -d
```

This will get the log and terminate the command immediately.

I don't know any other way to stop the logcat after some seconds, except CTRL+C.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wasn't what I was looking for it will do.

Comment: I am using something similar to what has been suggested here `adb logcat -v time -d` but still the command is stuck forever unless aborted manually.